# NE10 NEON library not working

Tags: floating-point, arm, signal-processing, neon

NE10 NEON optimized floating point library.

Is there any reference output available to check the output, I am currently working on checking the output validity of functions in NE10. I am working with GNU octave to check input and output.

Is the output-input correspondence already checked by the team? 
I did some preliminary analysis on FFT and here are the results.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B318pI7x2QVccXhNUWdiYlhmUWs/edit Please Comment.

My Fir filter after many trials ended up like this....
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c5ktcQ6VYlK2im3P2yGNNxRAZonssCApdLS7qkQwq6M/edit
Please tell if anyone has checked the real working of code other than simulations with random numbers.
I am giving my best to get the output but its always distorted.
Please help!!!!!- I need to make use of this library.
Thanks

Comment: You should put an issue on their github page if you suspect an error or directly this question. https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He has already posted this on the Ne10 Github issue tracker and the ARM website. I've already responded in several locations that the FFTs (both real and complex) and FIRs are fully unit tested and conformance tested. Conformance tests compare output from our functions against output from Matlab functions. I suggested, perhaps, his input structures were not properly populated and that he review how to populate the structure type from examples on stackoverflow (not re-post the same question here). I'll triple check our outputs but please keep the conversation to one thread if you're still having trouble.

https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/issues/46I

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this questions has been asked but I have run into similar problem when trying to use NE10 on a native (ndk's) jni application for android.

In my case everything was ok when I run NE10_dsp_unit_test_smoke application bundled with NE10, but the fft functions returned bad results when linking the library to my jni application (strange fft bin values etc...).

It turned out that the NE10 android build flags are not compatible with with ndk's armeabi-v7a-hard.

To fix this I replaced the NE10's generated build flags in $(NE10_LIB_DIR)/build/modules/CMakeFiles/NE10.dir/flags.make with the ones generated by the ndk and everything started to work fine.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what did you do to make Ne10 compiled with hard floating compatible with android ndk? I'm getting a weird error saying that .h are not found if a use the Ne10 compiled with hard floating enabled. Is it right to assume that hard floating features will increase performance over soft?

Comment: Hi VMMF. AFAIR all I had to do is rebuild my application for hard float, copy the flags from the compiler output and put them into the NE10 cmake file. I don't recall having trouble with headers, but it sounds like an SDK installation problem. I am sorry The hard float performance of floating point code is much much better. One of the libraries